# Highstock - navigator selection jumps to the right if moved after selecting in the chart

Tags: highcharts

I'm experiencing really strange behavior.
If I resize the timespan selection in the Navigator, I can scroll the selection left and right as many times as I want.
But is i sekect area directly in the chart, it zooms in to the selection, but afterwards if I try to scroll the selection in Navigator, the selection jumps to the right side of Navigator and stays there.

Any ideas what may be the difference between resizing with these two approaches? Are there any specific events trigerred after resizing in the chart vs in Navigator?

Comment: It may be connected to the data - is it sorted ascending? Don't you have any strings in data? You need to setup live example (e.g. jsFiddle) to get better answers.

Comment: no, it is timextamp,value in several series. It is sorted well, I had some trouble with two points with same timestamp in the data load function and it resulted in highcharts #15 error, it is all fixed now. Resizing in navigator fixes it, I am now trying to find the way to resize the navigator by software (for example for 1ms, just to see if it will be the way to fix it)

Comment: @PawełFus I've checked and it seems to be fine. What I don't get is why it works well when resizing the Navigator, but jumps to the right when I've selected the area in the chart and tried to drag it afterwards.

Comment: strange - if I disable Rangeselector, it works as it should!

Comment: As I said before, without code and live example it won't be possible to help you..

Comment: My problem is that it is unreleased feature, not available publically. I found the cause - I had rangeselector selected property set, but the range shown in the chart didnt match the preselected timespan. After removing the 'selected:1' it works now.